# How to run flakey commands within set -e context?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I want to protect most of my bash script with `set -e`, in order to fail early and loudly when an error is detected during the script's processing. However, I still want to be able to run some commands that are actually expected to fail, such as using `grep` to evaluate the presence/absence of some file content that is used to direct the control flow of the rest of the script. How can I run `grep` within a `set -e` context, such that A) grep is allowed to fail and B) grep's exist status is recorded for access by the rest of the script?

In ordinary POSIX sh, I would do something like:

```
grep 'needle' haystack >/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    handle_grep_results
else
    handle_grep_no_results
fi
```

However, when `set -e` is specified before this section, then the script exits early whenever grep fails to find the needle. One way to work around this is to temporarily disable the protections with `set +e`, and then re-enable them after the section, but I would prefer to leave the protections on, if that makes sense. Is this possible with bash?

Comment: I would think of `-e` as a debugging aid to help you catch undesirable situations as you _develop_ code rather than to be holistically set in mission-critical code. In that sense, I use it in a similar manner to assert.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the return status of `grep`:

```
grep -q luck myfile.txt || no_luck=1
```

Shell utilities use the return status to communicate with the shell; what they are communicating is not necessarily an error condition. As the grep example shows, it can be a simple boolean. In fact, the `[[` builtin (and its friends `[` and `test`) do precisely that: use the status code to return a boolean result. That doesn't make those utilities "flakey".

`set -e` ignores non-zero status returns from commands executed within a conditional or on the left-hand side of a `||` or `&&` connector, which makes it possible to use `set -e`.

Having said that, `-e` is a very blunt tool and its use in production code is not generally recommended. You can always explicitly fail using `||`:

```
important_setup || exit 1
```

Comment: thanks for the typo mentions, i def scrambled those kebaabs

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` command seems to contain a couple of typos (an extra `#` and a missing space before `]`), but more generally, you should understand that the very *purpose* of `if` is to run a command and check its exit code. Anything which looks like

```
command
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
```

is more compactly and idiomatically written

```
if command; then
```

and in this context, a failure exit status from `command` is not a condition which causes `set -e` to terminate the script (because then you couldn't have `else` clauses in scripts with `set -e`!)

In this particular example where both the `then` and `else` blocks contain simple commands, you can simplify to the shorthand

```
grep -q 'needle' haystack && handle_grep_results || handle_grep_no_results
```

which also suggests

```
command || true
```

when you simply don't care whether `command` succeeded or not in a script with `set -e`.

(Notice also `grep -q` over `grep >/dev/null` - the former implies `-m 1`, i.e. `grep` can close the file and return success as soon as it finds the *first* match.)